# Libreoffice 6.3 can't "see" Other Locations

Tags: mount, samba, libreoffice

I have shares to a NAS set up.
If I use Nautilus I can see these shares - they are automounted on boot.
I'm using Samba and they are /media/xxxx type shares
The shares are all working fine however when I try and save in (for example) writer, there is only the option to save to the local machine. The shares do not show up. under "other locations" I only see "Computer"

I can navigate to the NAS - Computer/media/xxxx which is OK for me but for other users just being able to save to xxxx as was possible before would be good. Has something changed in Libre 6.3? Id there a way to "see" the shared NAS location?

It appears to be only a problem with libreoffice because, for example, I can navigate to the shared drive when I want to attach a file in webmail.

Comment: If you select Save As rather than just Save can you also then select Other Locations which will give you your NAS? - That's how it works on my 18.04 LTS with LO 6.3.0.4

Comment: Is libreoffice installed as a snap? Please check with `snap list`.

Comment: Graham - thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately the problem still exists with save as

Comment: Mook765 - Libreoffice 6.3.0.4 is listed using snap list command. In home/snap I can see libreoffice  changed last Sunday - this problem is recent so could it be that this is the first snap version of libreoffice I've had?